# Oracle - Display Multiple cursors Output as single select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have three cursors in my pl/sql block.
Cursor a is returning a1, a2, a3 columns, cursor b is returning b2, b2, b3 columns and cursor c is returning c1, c2, c3 columns.

```
DECLARE 
cursor a is
 select a1, a2,a3 
 from table_a;

cursor b(id number) is
 select b1, b2,b3
 from table_b 
 where table_b.id = id;

cursor c(id number) is
 select c1,c2,c3
 from table_c
where table_c.id = id;
BEGIN
--   
END;
```

How I can give output as

```
a1   a2    a3    b1    b2   b3    c1   c2    c3
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'd guess  that you want a single cursor whose query joins the three tables.

Comment: Is one of the columns in cursor `a` the value of the `id` parameter  in cursor `b` and `c`?  Is  the value of the `id` parameter  the same for cursor `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the scenario below.

```
    create table table_a (id int, a1 varchar2(20), a2 varchar2(20), a3 varchar2(20));
    create table table_b (id int, b1 varchar2(20), b2 varchar2(20), b3 varchar2(20));
    create table table_c (id int, c1 varchar2(20), c2 varchar2(20), c3 varchar2(20));

    insert into table_a values (1, 'The', 'Quick', 'Brown');
    insert into table_b values (1, 'Fox', 'Jumped', 'Over');
    insert into table_c values (1, 'The', 'Lazy', 'Dog');

    DECLARE
    v_a table_a%ROWTYPE;
    v_b table_b%ROWTYPE;
    v_c table_c%ROWTYPE;
    CURSOR abc IS SELECT a.a1, a.a2, a.a3, b.b1, b.b2, b.b3, c.c1, c.c2, c.c3
                  FROM table_a a
                  JOIN table_b b on (a.id=b.id)
                  JOIN table_c c on (a.id=c.id);
    BEGIN
      OPEN abc;
      LOOP
        FETCH abc INTO v_a.a1, v_a.a2, v_a.a3, v_b.b1, v_b.b2, v_b.b3, v_c.c1, v_c.c2, v_c.c3;
        EXIT WHEN abc%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_a.a1||' '||v_a.a2||' '||v_a.a3||' '||v_b.b1||' '||
                             v_b.b2||' '||v_b.b3||' '||v_c.c1||' '||v_c.c2||' '|| v_c.c3);
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /

    The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

    SQL>
```

The assumption is that it is OK to join these three tables, because you are outputting the values together, implying they have a relationship of some kind.   However, this is a guess, because you didn't explicitly state that in your question.

Still, my answer does literally answer your question.  Even if you setup  3 cursors, rather than 1, the way you would concatenate output is no different than the way I did it in this example.